# Reproducir .mp3 alojado en googledrive con android

Tags: android

llevo varios dias buscando información sobre esto, estoy haciendo una app para reproducir musica y necesito reproducir archivos .mp3 que esten alojados en mi cuenta de google Drive, Dropbox o en cualquier sitio para almacenar archivos en la nube. si me podrian pasar alguna información sera de gran ayuda.

Answer (score 2):

Te recomiendo que a la hora de formular seas más especifico o por lo menos muestres algo que hayas hecho, así tenemos por donde empezar. Igualmente, hace poco estuve trabajando con MediaPlayer, la clase de Android para reproducir audios. Te recomiendo que te leas la [documentación](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html) o que intentes seguir este buen [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0LWEthYRlOI). Aquí te dejo un ejemplo de una prueba que he hecho con un archivo mío alojado en la nube.

```
//play from url
public void playURL(){

    String finalURL = "https://drive.google.com/open?id=1cEhQvS5Nmnsynvlt44EYhi3cdWC-tSJX";

    if (player == null){
        Log.d(Constants.AUDIO_LOG_TAG, "Player is null. Call init() before using it! ");
        return;
    }
    try {
       player.reset();
        Log.d(Constants.AUDIO_LOG_TAG, "Playing from url: " + finalURL);
        player.setDataSource(finalURL);
        player.prepareAsync();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(Constants.AUDIO_LOG_TAG, "Error playing file " + finalURL, e);
    }
```

Te repito, primero mira toda la documentación de MediaPlayer porque hay una gran cantidad de información relevante: estados de MediaPlayer, callbacks, qué es reset, release... etc.

Espero que te haya sido de ayuda.